# Is there a way to add an asset pipeline in play framework?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I have a set of files that must be treated when the application starts and, only in DEV, retreated when one of them changes.

The files all together produce a massive JS file.

Is it possible to do this in play ?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Asset pipeline is described in the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Assets